# What is the distance between the connected components of the curve $z^2+\left(\overline{z}\right)^2 = 2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> What is the distance between the curve's two separated disconnected components?
>   $$z^2 + \left(\overline{z}\right)^2 = 2$$

I know the distance between two curves is the minimal distance between a pair of points such that one point is on one curve, and the other is on the other curve.

Comment: Write $z = x+iy$ and simplify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have $\Re(z^2)=1$, or if you write $z=x+iy$, the two branches of the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$, $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.
Then it is clear the minimal distance is $2$, achieved by $\pm 1$ (just look at the distance between the real-part components).

Comment: That’s how I saw the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by $2$, then

$2(z^2+\overline{z}^2)=4$

Using the identity $2(a^2+b^2)=(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2$, obtain

$(z+\overline{z})^2+(z-\overline{z})^2=4$

We recognize $z+\overline{z}=2\text{Re}(z)$ and $z-\overline{z}=2i\text{Im}(z)$, then

$\text{Re}(z)^2-\text{Im}(z)^2=1$

We therefore have a hyperbola in the complex plane, whose vertices the reader should easily recognize.  The distance between the branches is then just the distance between these vertices, which the reader should now be able to render easily.